# MySQL Query array return as undefine from function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, node-modules

NodeJs MySQL query rows array returned as undefined to calling function.
When I print the print in the source function is is populated with data.

The following function is in a NodeJS module:

```
   quesAnswers: (request, response) => {
      console.log ( '/quesAnswers ' + request.params.quesID );
      quesID = request.params.quesID;
      if (request.session.loggedin) {
         let dbc = require('../mods/db.js');
         dbc.query(`
            SELECT sa.*
            FROM  sa
            WHERE sa.id =  ?
            ORDER BY cdate DESC
         `, 
         values = [ quesID ],
         function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
              response.render('pages/err', { err: err });
              return( null );
            } else {
               console.log ( 'arows: ', rows.length );
               return( rows );
            }
          })
      } else {
         response.render('pages/please_login');
         return( null );
      }   
   }
```

I call this from another function in the same module as follows:

```
               arows =  module.exports.quesAnswers(request, response);
               console.log ( 'arows.length: ', arows.length );
               response.render('pages/test_ques_view', { qdata: rows, adata: arows  });
```

When I run it I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (/u01/WorkSpace/0050-AilarPOC/220.portal/node/mods/tests.js:281:54)
```

Comment: it's asynchronous code, You cannot return result as regular synchronous method